# Analyse effect of groups on raster maps

Tags: raster, r, spatial-statistics, analysis

I work with a mechanistic model that uses climate data to simulate some specific output for different time steps and spatial locations. Now I want to investigate the effect of different climate data sources on the model output. To do this, I varied the climate data and ran the model with otherwise constant settings; the groups are:

- Climate model that produces the climate data
- Emission scenarios with different assumption underlying the climate
  data from the same climate model
- Spatial resolution of the climate data
- Downscaling method to arrive at the specific spatial resolution

I have produced now a bunch of rasters with my model driven by the varying climate data.

Now I would like to extract the effects of the different groups of climate data on the model output and produce raster maps showing at which spatial locations there is the most variation in model output.

I was thinking about applying a principal component analysis to avoid pairwise comparisons of the simulations.

Would a PCA be an appropiate method or is there a better way of comparing the different groups? And what would be the next step after doing the PCA and calculating the loadings?